# Python Popen stdout output coming in stderr

Tags: python, subprocess, wireshark, tshark

I am have to capture output of `tshark -D` using python `subprocess`.
Here is `tshark -D` output,

`$ tshark -D
1. eth0
2. any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces)
3. lo`

And using python it gives,

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["tshark", "-D"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) ###1
>>> 1. eth0
2. any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces)
3. lo
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["tshark", "-D"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE) ###2
>>> p.stderr.read()
'1. eth0\n2. any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces)\n3. lo\n'
>>> p.stdout.read()
''
```

In #1, after entering command it gives output. And in #2, required output comes in `stderr`. Why is it giving results like this ?

Comment: unrelated: use `out, err = p.communicate()` instead of `out = p.stdout.read(); err = p.stderr.read()` the latter may deadlock if the subprocess generates enough output to fill the corresponding OS pipe buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all output whether the subprocess prints on stdout or stderr, you could use `stderr=STDOUT` and `subprocess.check_output`:

```
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

all_output = check_output(['tshark', '-D'], stderr=STDOUT)
```

`tshark` manual says:

> -D  Print a list of the interfaces on which TShark can capture, and exit.

It doesn't specify that the output must be on stderr. Though on my system it prints the diagnostic information only to stderr. Stdout might be reserved for printing captured data.

Answer (score 0):

`tshark -D` always prints to stderr. In case #1, since you did not capture the stderr, it is printed to your console.

In case #2, since you capture both stdout and stderr, stdout ==> '' and stderr ==> the output.

Comment: thanks, but it raises another question why does it print in `stderr` and not in `stdout`?

Answer (score 0):

For # 1: 
Because you have not process the standard pipe and output, so the print out of the command will just print there in the screen. When you want to process the standard pipe, you need both process the stdout and stderr. Otherwise you actually cannot capture the standard pipe. When you specify a standard pipe, you should handle the standard error print out at the same time.

It's more like this below, if you have a function under the module named "func_my.py":

```
def func_my():
    print "Hello"
    return "World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func_my()
```

When you call this function, if you don't process the console output, the string "hello" will be directly show in the console output.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "func_my.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This will always print the "hello".

For #2: You do capture the standard output and error put, but you have made a mistake. You have put all the pipe to both stdout and stderr. The right way should bwlow:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["tshark", "-D"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stderr.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
p.stdout.read()
"WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-UBTaGc/pkcs11: No such file or directory\ntshark: There are no interfaces on which a capture can be done\n"
```

Hope will hep you!

Comment: And note that the code you have specified for question 2 is just like you called the standard pipe for twice. The first time you will get the out put, the second time you will get an empty string. Just like what you have got.

Comment: thanks for pointing that i was not capturing stderr in #1. But I didn't understand why is it sending output to `stderr` but, not to `stdout`?

Comment: "When you want to process the standard pipe, you need both process the stdout and stderr." What do you want to say with that? You can happily process only one of them.

Comment: Very true. Actually I am using `stderr`. But this is unusual. I am  trying to understand the logic behind it Anyways answer given by @J.F. Sebastian is closer to a conclusion.